# How can I check if the player clicks (or doesn't) on a target within a time limit?

Tags: timer

In GameMaker, I'm trying to set up something like this:

The player will need to click on some object within three seconds. If they click on it within the timeframe, I'll do one thing (call `room_restart()`). Otherwise the game is over.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will need two variables and set alarm[0] for 3 seconds (or however many you want) in the create event of whatever is being clicked or handling the clicking. One can be called click the other timeup. Set both to zero. click will be used to check if the player clicked within the amount of time given. timeup will only be used to see if the time is up. Add the event for alarm[0] and make sure you set timeup to 1. Then make a click event and have it first check if timeup still equals 0.... if so set click to 1.
then you can use this click variable for whatever you want. If it's 1 the player managed to click it in time. If it's zero the player failed. In my example I added another object that simply changes color depending on if the first object was clicked.

You can download my two example below if you want.
One is all in code the other is all in drag and drop.

There is a black button that you have 5 seconds to click starting as soon as the game starts. There is also a white box that will change color after 5 seconds depending on if you clicked it or not. It will turn green if the black button was clicked and red if it was not.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/yiauc1u7own2ii4/Click_Timer_Example.zip

If this isn't quite what you were going for tell me because I was slightly confused by your description. I just went with what it sounded like you needed rather than just detecting when the player is not clicking because while possible that wouldn't be a very good way to solve this problem.

Comment: You should post at least part of your solution on your answer, giving a link is not recommended since it can go off in the future.

Comment: Ahh k one minute... Kinda new to stack exchange. Not really new to gamemaker though.